# Inline Javascript Audio Player/ Sound Manager 2

Tags: wordpress, soundmanager2, wordpress-thesis-theme

I would like to implement this audio player,

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

into my band website that I am working on

http://thewintonsbluegrass.com.

It is a Wordpress site running on the Thesis Theme framework. I looked through the players documentation but I couldn't figure the thing out. :D Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help to anyone who looked at my question. I figured it out now. I added the js files included in the plugin to the  of my theme and followed the rest of the direction in the readme.